# Pattern recognition and Machine Learning reference

Tags: reference-request

My main reference for machine learning and pattern recognition is [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738). But I want a complementary reference to this which has more exercises and explains the mathematical stuff in more details, e.g. formulas and proofs.

Comment: The book by Duda, Hart and Stork may help.

Comment: @AtulIngle: Pattern classification? That's a good one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another good book is:
 - [Pattern Recognition by Theodoridis and Koutroumbas](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Pattern_recognition.html?id=gAGRCmp8Sp8C&redir_esc=y)

It's about classifiers, features and clustering in the context of pattern recognition.

It contains all the mathematical stuff you want, and backs everything up with references to papers, books, etc. It has no exercises, so for that you need to look somewhere else.

Also see this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390974/statistical-machine-learning-books/9409489#9409489) on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern Recognition by Theodoridis and Koutroumbas (Suggested above) has a companion Matlab book which has lot of Matlab exercises and goes along with the main text book. Check it out>>
[Introduction to Pattern Recognition: A Matlab Approach](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Pattern_Recognition_A_Ma.html?id=9ysEF1OMuycC)

Answer (score 1):

The most popular choices seem to be

- [Machine Learning: a Probabilistic Perspective](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/) by Murphy
- [Pattern classification](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471056693) by Duda et all
- [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie et all. It is free from Stanford.
- [Mining of Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html), free from Stanford.
- [Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.HomePage), free available online.
- [Learning from data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600490069). by Abu-Mostafa. It comes with Caltech [video lectures](http://work.caltech.edu/telecourse.html)

Also noteworthy

- [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.html) by Mackay, free.
- [Classification, Parameter Estimation and State Estimation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470090138) by van der Heijden.
- [Computer Vision: Models, Learning, and Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107011795), by Prince
- [Probabilistic Graphical Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262013193)
  by Koller. Has an accompanying course on Coursera.